# Where are the Google Admin SDK libraries?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I would like to work with the Google Admin SDK and get information about our domain's email settings per user. I refer to [Developer's Guide | Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/)

I am comfortable approaching the problem in Java, Python, and C# and all three languages have examples included in the documentation.

**Where can I get all these libraries shown in the documentation?**

C#

```
using Google.GData.Apps;
using Google.GData.Apps.GoogleMailSettings;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
```

Java

```
import sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.GmailSettingsService;
```

Python

```
import gdata.apps.emailsettings.client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are located here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/libraries

If you work through the [Java QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java), these three imports aren't included and the provided quick start code won't compile.

```
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.DirectoryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory;
```

It seems the Java portion of this project is in need of an update.

Note the Maven and Gradle builds on the Java download page - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/admin/directory_v1 - show this error message:

> This library is in the process of uploading to the central Maven repository.  Please check back in a few hours.

I've seen that message there for a couple months now.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 kinds of APIs for Google Apps. The old style "GData" Atom based APIs and the new API Discovery Service compliant "Google APIs" (modern infra).

The Email Settings API is an old style GData API so you need the GData API client libraries.

The GData API client libraries are available for download from here:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries